# Что за конструкция a.a = {} = 2 и как она работает?

Tags: javascript

Попалась такая конструкция, но нигде не могу найти что это значит.

Как это называется и что оно делает?

По идее сначала `а.а` становиться равно пустому объекту а потом?

Почему в итоге в консоли выведет `{a:2}`?

```js
let a = {}
a.a = 1
a.a = {} = 2 //что это значит
console.log(a)
```

```
a.a = a = 2 // это выдает circular посередине
```

Comment: @Grundy помоги.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1758750/7791165

Comment: @Burg, призывы так не работают :-) оповещение будет только если пользователь оставлял комментарий, либо делал правку.

Comment: В принципе ответ уже дан

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, ваш загадочный фрагмент кода имеет академический интерес, хоть ничего полезного и не делает)

В череде присвоений операции проходят справа налево. Поэтому порядок такой:

1. `{} = 2`: Поскольку присвоить объекту (да и вообще не-переменной) значение нельзя, мы имеем дело с пограничным случаем деструктурирования без переменной. Если вы вместо двойки будете использовать `null` или `undefined`, сообщение об ошибке это подтвердит. Деструктурирование других примитивов возможно: `{ toString } = 2` присваивает переменной `toString` функцию `2..toString`.
2. При этом присваивание, даже с деструктурированием, возвращает второй операнд, т. е. `2`.
3. Это значение в конце концов присваивается свойству `a.a`;

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял